# How to reset Combobox IndexStatus to -1 after selection is made

Tags: c#, combobox

I'm trying to set the `IndexStatus` of `Combobox` to -1 after the selection is made and submitted. But it does not work without a caveat being present.
I've tried googling this issue for a while now. Most fixes are cheap short-term fixes and some just don't work.

**DropDownStyle**: *DropDownList*

[GIF of the program in use with current code](https://i.imgur.com/dgMUNFv.gifv)

```
private void cmbStatusIndex()
{
    if (cmbStatus.Items.Count > 0)
    cmbStatus.SelectedIndex = -1;
}

private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbStatus.Text == "")
        return;
    try
    {
        cmbStatusIndex();
        Edit(false);
        permitsBindingSource.EndEdit();
        dataGridView.Refresh();
        //  txtStatus.SelectedIndexChanged(txtStatus.SelectedIndex = -1);
        //  txtStatus.SelectedIndex = -1; //THIS LINE OF CODE RESETS THE COMBOBOX TO DEFAULT BUT IT ALSO DOESN'T SHOW IN THE DATAGRIDVIEW
        txtSign.Clear();
        txtType.Clear();
        txtCity.Clear();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        appData.Permits.RejectChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: What issue you are facing with this code? Sorry I don't understand what you mean by `does not work without a caveat being present`?

Comment: Hi, sorry. If the gif worked (hopefully) you'll see how it doesn't send in the selected item from the ComboBox because it gets reset. Or other problems would be it would work; Submit > Shows text in DataGridview > and after clicking "New" the ComboBox selection would *Fade* away.

Comment: Because you are calling `cmbStatusIndex();` before refreshing the grid view. You should call it at last when you are clearing the textboxes.

Comment: I've already tried that. It still doesn't reset it.

Comment: Can you share the code of edit method? Also the code which uses selectedItem from comboBox and binds it to the gridview?

Comment: `  private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   Edit(true);
   txtSign.Focus();
  }
`